# "Where" clause doesn't work from C# when connecting to Exchange Online

Tags: c#, powershell, automation, exchange-server

I connect to Exchange Online via C# and can run a `Get-Mailbox` command without problem. But when I try

```
Get-Mailbox | Where LitigationHoldEnabled -eq $true
```

I get an error

> The term 'where.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The command runs just fine in PowerShell.
What am I missing?

```cs
            PSCredential credential = new PSCredential("xxxxx@yyyyyyyy.de", secpassword);
            string connectionUri = "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/";
            Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace( );
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
            command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", new Uri(connectionUri));
            command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
            command.AddParameter("Credential", credential);
            command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Basic");
            command.AddParameter("AllowRedirection", true);
            powershell.Commands = command;
            runspace.Open();
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> result = powershell.Invoke();
            if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0 || result.Count != 1)
            {
                powershell.Dispose();
                runspace.Dispose();

            }
            command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
            command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create("Get-Mailbox | Where-Object LitigationHoldEnabled - eq $true"));
            command.AddParameter("Session", result[0]);
            powershell.Commands = command;
            var Searches = powershell.Invoke();
        ....
            powershell.Dispose();
            runspace.Dispose();
```

Comment: `where` is normally a built-in alias for the `Where-Object` cmdlet, so use the latter instead to see if it bypasses the problem. That said, even if the absence of the alias were the problem, your symptom is mysterious: where does the `.exe` part in the error message come from if you didn't specify it? It makes sense to go looking for `where.exe` in the PATH if there's no `where` alias - and as a standard utility it should be found - but clearly wasn't in your case. Are you showing us the exact / all relevant code? As an aside: `Where-Object LitigationHoldEnabled` is sufficient.

Comment: With" | Where-Object"  the Error is 'The term 'Where-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program….' So no big difference.

Comment: `Get-Mailbox -Filter "LitigationHoldEnabled -eq '$true'"` should work.

Comment: This gives me a "The syntax is not supported by this runspace. This can occur if the runspace is in no-language mode." Error

Comment: "LanguageMode" of the Runspace is "FullLanguage", by the way...